Weakly compact cardinals in $L$: how long do branches take to appear?
Throughout, we work in $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L+}$ "There is a weakly compact cardinal," $\kappa$ is the first weakly compact cardinal and "tree" means "subtree of $2^{<\kappa}$ of height $\kappa$"

Despite the weak compactness of $\kappa$ "in reality" the model $L_\kappa$ does not satisfy "$\mathsf{Ord}$ is weakly compact;" see Enayat/Hamkins. On the other hand, by true weak compactness of $\kappa$, there is some $\lambda>\kappa$ such that every tree $T$ in $L_{\kappa+1}$ has a path in $L_\lambda$.

What is the least such $\lambda$?

More generally, what is the function $\kappa^+\setminus\kappa\rightarrow\kappa^+$ sending each $\alpha\in[\kappa+1,\kappa^+)$ to the least $\lambda$ such that every subtree of $2^{<\kappa}$ in $L_\alpha$ has a path in $L_\lambda$?

Very nice question! My result with Enayat is about definable class trees and definable paths, so it only rules out $\lambda=\kappa+1$ as not large enough. It could be that the paths come right away after that, or perhaps one must wait a long time, but I'm just not sure.

A silly upper bound is the least ordinal $\delta$ greater than $\kappa$ such that $L_\delta \prec_{\Sigma_1} L_{\kappa^+}$. (The given $\kappa$-tree $T$ is definable over $L_\kappa$, so we can state 'if $T$ is a $\kappa$-tree then it has an infinite branch' as a $\Sigma^1_1$-statement over $L_\kappa$.) I am unsure if it is optimal.

Is there anything known about the "case" $\kappa=\omega$? It seems plausible to me that there are definable trees on $\omega$ where one has to wait until $L_{\omega_1^{ck}}$ or so for a branch.

@MihaHabič Note that my trees are $2$-branching. Branches through $2^{<\omega}$ trees arrive in $L_{\omega+1}$ by the low basis theorem. If we shift to $\omega^{<\omega}$, then indeed we get trees whose branches arrive arbitrarily late in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ (since otherwise the set of computable ill-founded trees on $\omega$ would be hyperarithmetic), but that's a different setup from my question.

@HanulJeon Maybe I'm missing something, but can't we phrase an arbitrary $\Sigma^1_1$ statement about $L_\kappa$ in terms of the ill-foundedness of some tree? If so, doesn't that make your upper bound sharp?

I am unsure since $\kappa$ is not countable. Well-foundedness is $\Delta^1_1$ assertion over $V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible $\kappa$ since $V_\kappa$ becomes closed under countable sequences, so the quantifier over ill-founded sequences can be a set quantifier.

@HanulJeon Yes, but the trees in this question have height $\kappa$, not height $\omega$.

Oh, I have to correct my first comment that the precise $\Sigma^1_1$-formulation is "If $T$ is a $\kappa$ tree then we have a branch of length $\kappa$." (But still, the only existential quantifier outside of $L_\kappa$ is that quantifies a branch of length $\kappa$.)

@NoahSchweber Re your comment on trees $\subseteq{^{<\omega}\omega}$, shouldn't it be "trees who first get a branch in $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}+1}$"?

@FarmerS To clarify, you are saying every $\Sigma^1_1$ statement over $L_\kappa$ is equivalent to the statement of the form "some definable tree is ill-founded?" I am unsure if I understand the current discussion correctly. If my understanding is correct (and if ill-foundedness means there is no infinite branch), then the answer is no. If we instead ask "every $\Sigma^1_1$ statement over $L_\kappa$ is equivalent to 'a definable tree over $L_\kappa$ has branch of length $\kappa$'", I don't know.

@FarmerS I was thinking about the definition of the tree after reading your comment. I guess the nodes of the tree should have the form $(L_\alpha,X)$ for $X\subseteq L_\alpha$ and $\alpha<\kappa$, $L_\alpha\ni \vec{x}$, such that if $\phi(\vec{x})$ is $\exists Y \psi(Y,\vec{x})$ for some bounded $\psi$, then $(L_\alpha,X)\vDash \psi(X,\vec{x})$, and the node extension should be end extension. Is it what you considered?

@HanulJeon actually, thinking about it some more, I'm not seeing how to make that work.

@FaremerS Yes, I do not see how to guarantee the tree a $\kappa$-tree.

Right, that seems to be a challenge.

Actually it's strictly less than the less $\Sigma_1$-elementary level, because it's a $\Sigma_1$ statement about the parameter $\kappa$ to say "there is some $\alpha>\kappa$ such that in $L_\alpha$, every $\kappa$-tree which is definable from parameters over $L_\kappa$ has a $\kappa$-branch in $L_\alpha$", and therefore there is some such $\alpha<$ the $\Sigma_1$-elementary level.

It seems one characterization of $\lambda$ is that it is the least ordinal such that for each $n<\omega$, there is $\alpha<\lambda$ such that $L_\kappa\preccurlyeq_n L_\alpha$.

Here is a characterization of $\lambda$, but of course your question is somewhat ambiguous as to what counts as an answer.
For $n<\omega$, let $\alpha_n$ be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\kappa<\alpha$ and $L_\kappa\preccurlyeq_n L_\alpha$. (This exists by weak compactness.) Then $\lambda=\sup_{n<\omega}\alpha_n$.
Proof: To see $\lambda\leq\sup_{n<\omega}\alpha_n$, let $T$ be a $\kappa$-tree which is $\Sigma_m$-definable from parameters over $L_\kappa$. Let $T'$ be the interpretation of such a definition of $T$, over $L_{\alpha_{m+3}}$. Then $T'\cap L_\kappa=T$, and $T'$ has nodes at level $\kappa$, and these give a $\kappa$-branch through $T$, hence in $L_{\alpha_{m+3}}\subseteq L_\lambda$.
To see the converse, fix $n$. Define the natural $\kappa$-tree over $L_\kappa$, searching for a wellfounded model $M$ such that $L_\kappa\preccurlyeq_n M$. This is definable over $L_\kappa$, at roughly $\Sigma_{n+3}$ or so (without using parameters). (At height $\eta<\kappa$ in the tree, where $\eta$ is a reasonably closed limit ordinal, we would have built the restriction $M\upharpoonright\eta$ of the planned eventual model $M$ on elements given by ordinals $<\eta$, and specified its $\Sigma_n$-theory on those elements, and would have also produced some isomorphism between $L_\eta$ and some $\in$-intitial segment of $M\upharpoonright\eta$ (and this must remain an $\in$-initial segment from this node onward). The $\Sigma_n$-theory in $L_\kappa$ of elements of $L_\eta$ must match that of their images in $M\upharpoonright\eta$. Whenever we specify an existential statement in the theory in one of these nodes (of height $\eta$), it must be witnessed in the same node with some element $<\eta$. (That is, if the node specifies the formula $\exists x\ \varphi(x,\vec{p})$, then there must be some $\alpha<\eta$ such that it also specifies $\varphi(\alpha,\vec{p})$.) We also demand that $M\upharpoonright\eta$ is wellfounded; any $\kappa$-branch will then give a wellfounded model, since $\kappa$ is inaccessible.)
Now just note that from a $\kappa$-branch through $T_n$, if $M$ is the corresponding model, then $M=L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha>\kappa$ such that $L_\kappa\preccurlyeq_n L_\alpha$. But we can't have such a branch $\in L_{\alpha_n}$, since we can't have such an $M\in L_{\alpha_n}$, since otherwise $L_{\alpha_n}$ could compute the Mostowski collapse of $M$ and that would give $\alpha<\alpha_n$, a contradiction. (But we get a branch through $T_n$ definable over $L_{\alpha_n}$, since there is a surjection $\kappa\to L_{\alpha_n}$ definable over $L_{\alpha_n}$.) So $\lambda\geq\sup_{n<\omega}\alpha_n$.

And this argument has an affinity with the argument in my result with Enayat, where a similar underlying order is used.

This is great! (I've heard this called a "Welch-style characterization," incidentally, if I'm not misusing the term; @JoelDavidHamkins?)

I haven't heard that, but it makes sense, in light of arguments I've heard from Philip.

@JoelDavidHamkins Hang on ... :P
